# How to merge two cell array columns with added space in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

I have two `25557x1` cell arrays, month and time:

```
month = '2015/08/21'
        '2015/08/21'
        '2015/08/21'
         ...
time = '08:10:12.0'
       '08:30:12.0'
       '08:50:12.0'
         ...
```

I want to merge the two cell arrays into one so that the format is:

```
date = '2015/08/21 08:10:12.0'
       '2015/08/21 08:30:12.0'
       '2015/08/21 08:50:12.0'
         ...
```

horzcat turns these two cell arrays into two columns--I only want one column. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`strcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) to horizontally concatenate the cell arrays of strings and insert a space between the two

```
out = strcat(month, {' '}, time);
```

Note that we have to put the space inside of a cell array so that `strcat` doesn't strip out the space

> Trailing spaces in character array inputs are ignored and do not appear in the output. This is not true for inputs that are cell arrays of strings

Comment: That did exactly what I wanted! Thanks!

Comment: @Strak Updated with a better option.